# Is there an r package similar to LEM for analyzing contingency tables?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, contingency-tables, log-linear

Is there an R package for log-linear analysis that is similar to [LEM](http://members.home.nl/jeroenvermunt/)?

Here is an example LEM script

```
***INPUT***

* A = Personality

* B = Cholesterol

* C = Blood Pressure

man 3
dim 2 2 2
lab A B C
mod {AB, AC}
dat [716 79
     207 25
     819 67
     186 22]
```

The LEM program can be used to perform log-linear analysis and to test the association between different variables.

The problem is that all of the R packages that I've found assume that there is some sort of file that you are reading data from.

With LEM, I can input the individual frequencies from a contingency table directly into into the program as data.

For example, the above script is essentially just the data from 2 2x2 contingency tables. I don't have to read in any data file.

Comment: Why is it difficult to read in the data and form the contingency tables?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen because I don't actually have any data to read in. All I will have is a paper version of the contingency table. There will be no data file.

Comment: Then  you can just type the table into R---or if it is large, type it into a file, then read it in.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That's what I'm asking how to do. Everything that I have found online so far assumes that I'm getting my data from reading data that is in a file. The R documentation doesn't give a full example and since we never used R to do this in class, I can't refer to my class notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create the data**

I don't actually know how LEM would pour that array into a 2 x 2 x 2 table, so I've assumed it does it column wise.  I also don't know what the levels of A B and C are supposed to be, so I've called them 1 and 2.
Here's how to make your table

```
dat <- array(c(716, 79, 207, 25, 819, 67, 186, 22), 
             dim=c(2,2,2), 
             dimnames=list(A=1:2, B=1:2, C=1:2))
```

**Fit a model**

First with the slightly clunky base R functions that closely mirror the LEM script

```
mod1 <- loglin(dat, margin=list(c('A','B'), c('A','C')))

1 - pchisq(mod1$lrt, mod1$df) ## manual likelihood ratio test
```

Now again with the MASS package's wrapper function that uses a formula interface

```
library(MASS) ## no need to install

mod2 <- loglm(~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C, data=dat)
```

Type

```
?loglin
```

and

```
?loglm
```

for more details.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I found a book [*An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis Using R*](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~presnell/Courses/sta4504-2000sp/R/R-CDA.pdf) that, as the title suggests, recreates some of the exercises in *An Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis* using R. They have plenty of worked examples of making two and three way contingency tables using R that don't require you to have to read in data.